# Wordpress Network with SSL for multiple domains

Tags: multisite, login, ssl

I am setting up a Wordpress Network and am not sure how I can secure login for each sub-site domain. I am using `Nginx` and `php7`

Main site: example.com

Site1: example1.com

Site2: example2.com

I setup `SSL` for the main site and login/admin pages with `HTTPS` works great. However, as far as I know, each sub site login/admin is under their domain so will need to somehow secure these domains also.

Example: `example1.com/wp-admin` needs to be under HTTPS.

1) Is there a way to force all sub-sites to login and go to admin pages under the main domain `example.com/wp-admin/`.

2) If not, how/what is the best method to secure all other domains.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not done this myself, but I'm guessing the first thing you'll need is an SSL certificate for each of the separate domains, or a single certificate that covers multiple domains.  Once you are using domain mapping in WP multisite, the web server is going to see the incoming domain example1.com as a completely different domain from example2.com.  Also, you are not going to be able to have someone log into example1.com and then have privileges in example.com unless they are a multisite superadmin.

Comment: How did you configure WP sites to use domains?  Did you install WP multisite subdomain?  Are you using any plugins?

Comment: @user42826 Not using any plugins as WP today handles mapping. The issue is that changing the website URL in WP also changes how they access the admin pages. So it seems if you want to offer secure login you will need to get a certificate that handles multiple domains

Comment: I have a subdirectory WP configuration and use Domain Mapping plugin to  map subsites to other domains.  I edit all sites using the main site and https.  Would you be interested in the full detail?

Comment: I would be but it seems the only plugins for domain mapping are paid (the free one on Wordpress plugins directory is outdated and no longer supported). It seems to be a shame we need a plugin when it work within core. please PM me.